# Over 1000 MB allocated in private KB in vb.net application after little time

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, memory, gdi

I have a vb.net application that uses SQL connections and SQL objects (like datatables and commands). Now I planned to test memory issues and see if there is something wrong about memory..

I have inserted timer and made it show specific form in my application every 1 second and close it..

This form contains very very simple form load code, just about populate combo boxes from SQL Server (standalone comboboxes and in datagrids).

Now, in resources monitor in memory tab and especially in private KB field, the memory is growing up and never releases, it reached 1 GB and more !

Why that happens often ?

Notes:

- Vb.net
- VS 2012
- SQL Server 2008
- Using DevExpress Components
- Calling `Dispose()` after using Connections.

I watched the GDI Objects memory, it releases every form close so i think it's not GDI memory problem.

timer working time is less than 5 Min.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: try to use DebugDiag to create a memory dump and see which objects use the most of the memory.

Comment: can we see some code before and around the timer?

Comment: Dim o As New onCommands
        o.Show()

Comment: that is timer code :)

Comment: What is this? `private KB field`

Comment: in the resources monitor,memory tab >> processes grid >> Private (KB) (column)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, for safety, you consider using the "Using" keyword. This will ensure as soon as your connections fall out of scope they are disposed. Any object that implements IDisposable can be used with a Using Statement.

```
Using conn as new SQLConnection(connString)
    'Do some stuff with your SQL connection
End Using
```

This is just good practice and means you don't have to use Try... Finally to ensure closed connections.

You will also need to look at other possible causes of your memory leak. May need to consider the scope of how you show the form, also. Try making the code that opens your form dispose the form, too;

```
Using frmFoo as new frmMain
   frmFoo.Show()
End Using
```